# Regex on pandas dataframe to change column names, then re-arrrage format of dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have dataframe with the following format.

[image]

Would like to modified the column names and rearranging the dataframe into the following format:-

[image]

I have tried the code below to convert the column names from object to list and then strip and split the string. But still have white spaces after doing so. Not sure why.

```
df_col_list=df.columns.tolist()
list =[]
for elem in df_col_list:
    list.extend(elem.strip().split(':'))
list
```

Moved to regex to replace the column name to fill those with ID column in the final dataframe format i desire.

```
well_pattern=re.compile(r'[A-Z]{4}\d{4}')
for item_list in list:
    wellname=re.findall(well_pattern,item_list)
    for n in wellname:
        fld, well_no= n[:4], int(n[4:8])
        item_list = item_list.replace(n, '%s_%d_0' % (fld, well_no))
    print(item_list)
```

It worked to change 'MNIF0001' to 'MNIF_1_0'. But how do i then use this output to fill the new columns in the final dataframe format..

I am now stuck and not sure how to proceed. Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change pattern for matching groups by `r'([A-Z]{4})(\d{4})(.+)'` and use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for new helper `DataFrame` - convert second column to integers, join together and assign back.

Then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex`, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and data cleaning - [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'MNIF0001:w':[2] * 5,
        'MNIF0010:w':[4] * 5,
        'MNIF0001:f':[6] * 5,
        'MNIF0010:f':[8] * 5,

}, index=['01-Feb-63','01-Mar-63','01-Apr-63','01-May-63','01-Jun-63'])
df.index.name = 'date'
print (df)
           MNIF0001:w  MNIF0010:w  MNIF0001:f  MNIF0010:f
date                                                     
01-Feb-63           2           4           6           8
01-Mar-63           2           4           6           8
01-Apr-63           2           4           6           8
01-May-63           2           4           6           8
01-Jun-63           2           4           6           8
```

---

```
well_pattern=re.compile(r'([A-Z]{4})(\d{4})(.+)')
df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract(well_pattern)
print (df1)
               0     1   2
MNIF0001:w  MNIF  0001  :w
MNIF0010:w  MNIF  0010  :w
MNIF0001:f  MNIF  0001  :f
MNIF0010:f  MNIF  0010  :f

df.columns = df1[0] + '_' + df1[1].astype(int).astype(str) + '_0' + df1[2]
print (df)
           MNIF_1_0:w  MNIF_10_0:w  MNIF_1_0:f  MNIF_10_0:f
date                                                       
01-Feb-63           2            4           6            8
01-Mar-63           2            4           6            8
01-Apr-63           2            4           6            8
01-May-63           2            4           6            8
01-Jun-63           2            4           6            8
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date','ID')).reset_index().sort_values(['ID','date'])
print (df)
        date         ID  f  w
4  01-Apr-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
0  01-Feb-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
8  01-Jun-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
2  01-Mar-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
6  01-May-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
5  01-Apr-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
1  01-Feb-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
9  01-Jun-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
3  01-Mar-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
7  01-May-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
```

EDIT: If need working with `ID` column only repalace `columns` to `ID`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date','ID')).reset_index().sort_values(['ID','date'])

well_pattern=re.compile(r'([A-Z]{4})(\d{4})')
df1 = df['ID'].str.extract(well_pattern)
df['ID'] = df1[0] + '_' + df1[1].astype(int).astype(str) + '_0'
print (df)
        date         ID  f  w
4  01-Apr-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
0  01-Feb-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
8  01-Jun-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
2  01-Mar-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
6  01-May-63   MNIF_1_0  6  2
5  01-Apr-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
1  01-Feb-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
9  01-Jun-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
3  01-Mar-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
7  01-May-63  MNIF_10_0  8  4
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, got it to work. How do i then apply regular expression on ID column to change the ID from MNIF0001 to MNIF_1_0 and so on. Like i was trying to do with regex in my question.

Comment: @jezreal. Thanks buddy, worked like a charm.
For my learning, if I were to do the regex on ID column (i.e. find MNIF0001 pattern and replace to MNIF_1_0) on after you do the str,split and df.stack(0) steps. How do i then do the coding? Meaning applying compile,findall,replace on ID column as values/series. Appreciate your help. i can see i doing that in the future on some pandas dataframe.

Comment: @ jexrael - let me know if it is unclear what i am asking.